# How to check "does not contain" in saql?

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, saql

I have written my saql like

```
q = load "Opportunities";
q = filter q by !('Opportunity.Name' in ["test","TEST ","Test"]);
q = group q by 'Opportunity.Name';
q = foreach q generate 'Opportunity.Name' as 'Opportunity.Name', count() as 'count';
```

Also I have tried

```
q = load "Opportunities";
q = filter q by 'Opportunity.Name' not in ["test","TEST ","Test"];
q = group q by 'Opportunity.Name';
q = foreach q generate 'Opportunity.Name' as 'Opportunity.Name', count() as 'count';
```

But in the final results I am getting the Opportunity names contains "Test","TEST"

Comment: What are you loading in the report?

Comment: I am loading Opportunities Dataset which i have created

Comment: It could be an issue with the left operand. Do you mind double checking the Opportunity.Name? Should it not be just 'Name'?

Comment: @NavalSharma It is Opportunity.Name only..

Comment: The filters in your question would exclude an exact match - are you looking to exclude a partial match (i.e., any opportunity with the word "Test" in the name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to exclude any opportunity with "Test" in the name I think you would want to use the matches operator.

```
q = load "Opportunities";
q = filter q by !('Opportunity.Name' matches "test") && !('Opportunity.Name' matches "Test") && !('Opportunity.Name' matches "TEST");
q = group q by 'Opportunity.Name';
q = foreach q generate 'Opportunity.Name' as 'Opportunity.Name', count() as 'count';
```

Comment: Note that the matches operator is not case-sensitive, so you don't have to match against "test", "Test" and "TEST" separately.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_operators_comparison.htm?search_text=matches